# VBA code for Extracting Symbols like "&&","&&-","&-" and numbers into different columns

Tags: vba

I am having a sheet which contains range of values like "5670&&2","1281&&-3&-5&&7",... etc. in Column A.

Kindly help me to extract the output in VBA in following way:

For E.g 5670&&2 I require A1 cell contains 5670,B1 cell contains &&,C1 cell contains 2.

For E.g 1281&&-3&-5&&7,I would require that A1 cell contains 1281,B1 cell contains &&-,C1 cell contains 3,D1 cell contains &-,E1 cell contains 5,F1 cell contains && and G1 cell contains 7.

Pls help in the same .

Thanks.,

Comment: Do you want to use a formula or as a macro launched from time to time?

Comment: I want a macro launched from time to time

Answer (score 1):

Here i have tried to write code to separate numbers from non-numbers. Numbers and non-numbers are copied to different columns, like Excel Text-To-Columns. Code is a little crazy, if u need i will provide comments. As input the ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells is used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SeparateNumbers()
  Dim targetRange As Range
  Dim cellRange As Range
  Dim charIndex As Integer
  Dim oneChar As String
  Dim nextChar As String
  Dim start As Integer
  Dim copiedCharsCount As Integer
  Dim cellValue As String
  Dim columnIndex As Integer

  Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells

  For Each cellRange In targetRange
    columnIndex = cellRange.Column
    start = 1
    copiedCharsCount = 0
    cellValue = cellRange.Value
    If (VBA.Strings.Len(cellValue) <= 1) Then GoTo nextCell

    For charIndex = 2 To Len(cellValue)
      oneChar = VBA.Strings.Mid(cellValue, charIndex - 1, 1)
      nextChar = VBA.Strings.Mid(cellValue, charIndex, 1)
      If VBA.IsNumeric(oneChar) And VBA.IsNumeric(nextChar) Then GoTo nextCharLabel
      If Not VBA.IsNumeric(oneChar) And Not VBA.IsNumeric(nextChar) Then GoTo nextCharLabel

      cellRange.Offset(0, columnIndex).Value = VBA.Strings.Mid(cellValue, start, charIndex - start)
      columnIndex = columnIndex + 1
      copiedCharsCount = copiedCharsCount + (charIndex - start)
      start = charIndex

nextCharLabel:
      If charIndex = Len(cellValue) Then
        cellRange.Offset(0, columnIndex).Value = VBA.Strings.Right(cellValue, charIndex - copiedCharsCount)
      End If
    Next charIndex

nextCell:
  Next cellRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more code. As a side product, function TextSplitToNumbersAndOther can be used independently as a formula to achieve the same effect.

To prevent accidental firing of the macro in a wrong sheet or a wrong column and overwriting neighbouring columns with scrap, named range "Start_point" should be defined by a user. Below this range in the same column, all data will be processed till the first blank row.

Spreadsheet example: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Extracting_symbols_into_columns.xls

Option Explicit

```
Sub ExtractSymbolsIntoColumns()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row_processed As Integer
Dim string_to_split As String
Dim columns_needed As Long
Dim counter As Long

row_processed = 1
 counter = 0
  Set rng = Range("Start_point")
    While rng.Offset(row_processed, 0).Value <> ""
      string_to_split = rng.Offset(row_processed, 0).Value
         columns_needed = TextSplitToNumbersAndOther(string_to_split)
          For counter = 1 To columns_needed
            rng.Offset(row_processed, counter).Value = _
              TextSplitToNumbersAndOther(string_to_split, counter)
          Next
         row_processed = row_processed + 1
      Wend
End Sub

Function TextSplitToNumbersAndOther(InputText As String, _
    Optional SplitPieceNumber As Long) As Variant

Dim piece_from_split(100)  As Variant
Dim char_from_input As String
Dim word_count As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim char_type(100) As Variant

 InputText = Trim(InputText)

   If Not IsNull(InputText) Then
     word_count = 1
      piece_from_split(word_count) = ""
       For counter = 1 To Len(InputText)
         char_from_input = CharFromTextPosition(InputText, counter)
          char_type(counter) = CharTypeAsNumber(char_from_input)
            If counter = 1 Then
              piece_from_split(word_count) = char_from_input
            Else
              If (char_type(counter - 1) = char_type(counter)) Then
                 piece_from_split(word_count) = piece_from_split(word_count) & char_from_input
                   'Merge for the same type
              Else
                 word_count = word_count + 1
                   piece_from_split(word_count) = char_from_input


              End If
            End If
       Next
   End If

  If SplitPieceNumber = 0 Then
    TextSplitToNumbersAndOther = word_count
  Else
      If SplitPieceNumber > word_count Then
         TextSplitToNumbersAndOther = ""
      Else
        TextSplitToNumbersAndOther = piece_from_split(SplitPieceNumber)
      End If
  End If

End Function

Function CharTypeAsNumber(InputChar As String, Optional PositionInString As Long) As Long

   If PositionInString = 0 Then PositionInString = 1

     If Not IsNull(InputChar) Then
       InputChar = Mid(InputChar, PositionInString, 1)
        Select Case InputChar
          Case 0 To 9
            CharTypeAsNumber = 1
          Case "a" To "z"
            CharTypeAsNumber = 2
          Case "A" To "Z"
            CharTypeAsNumber = 3
          Case Else
            CharTypeAsNumber = 4
         End Select
     Else
           CharTypeAsNumber = 0

     End If

End Function
Function CharFromTextPosition(InputString As String, TextPosition As Long) As String

   CharFromTextPosition = Mid(InputString, TextPosition, 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a UDF (user defined function) to achieve the objective.
Your two example are in an order (ascending) to filter out into adjacent columns in Excel (A, B, C, D...)

So is it correct to assume logically, that you will never have scenarios where you will have to break the string into non-adjacent columns? e.g. 1234 goes to A, && goes to C, 3 goes to D... resulting in A, C, D.

Asumption 2: That your splitted-string is not going to need columns more than Excel can provide.

Steps you may try:
 1. Check your string is not empty
 2. Split it by the characters other than numerics
 3. At the start and end of each non-numeric character you may proceed to the next adjacent column.

search help: Split a string into multiple columns in Excel - VBA